# error: code on pandas numerical column breaks with string formatting error

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in a table with `pandas`, and one of the columns has dates in the format YYYYMMMDD. It is read in as a numerical column in all my attempts so far.

I could digest it correctly (though slowly) with clunky code first, but then the current version hiccups in a way I don't understand.

So, this worked:

```
treatments['month'] = treatments['INDATUMA'] % 10000
treatments['day'] = treatments['INDATUMA'] % 100
treatments['month'] = (treatments['month']-treatments['day'])/100
```

(Though this ran last time in smaller data frames, the current version ran on the concatenation of all of them. In smaller test data, the code still runs fine, and breaks on the entire data.)

This breaks:

```
all_treatments['month'] = all_treatments.INDATUMA % 10000 // 100
```

This is the error message:

```
File "treatments2_noiopro.py", line 92, in <module>
   all_treatments['month'] = all_treatments.INDATUMA % 10000 // 100
 File "/home/seidav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 532, in wrapper
   return left._constructor(wrap_results(na_op(lvalues, rvalues)),
 File "/home/seidav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 479, in na_op
   result[mask] = op(x[mask], y)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I am using versions pandas 0.16.2 np19py26_0 and python 2.7.10 0 under Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use `pandas` native datetime functionality on the final concatenated dataframe, e.g.

```python
treatments['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(treatments['INDATUMA'])

#Now you can split up the date easy as pie
treatments['year'] = treatments['date'].dt.year
treatments['month'] = treatments['date'].dt.month
treatments['day'] = treatments['date'].dt.day
```

UPDATED

Comment: I am getting a warning and `/home/seidav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py:1170: DtypeWarning: Columns (8) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.`
 `data = self._reader.read(grows)`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "treatments2_noiopro.py", line 93, in <module>`
   `all_treatments['year'] = all_treatments['date'].year`
`File "/home/seidav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2150, in __getattr__
   (type(self).__name__, name))`
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'`

Comment: Need the `.dt` accessor! http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#basics-dt-accessors

Comment: Nice find! I knew there was a way. I'll update the answer.