# pandas dt accessor error, column made with to_datetime not datelike?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, accessor

I am confused by an error returned by my Python script:

```
all_treatments['date'] = pd.to_datetime(all_treatments['INDATUMA'])
all_treatments['year'] = all_treatments['date'].dt.year
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "treatments2_noiopro.py", line 93, in <module>
   all_treatments['year'] = all_treatments['date'].dt.year
 File "/home/seidav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2145, in __getattr__
   return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
 File "/home/seidav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 188, in __get__
   return self.construct_accessor(instance)
 File "/home/seidav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2528, in _make_dt_accessor
   raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike "
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

What am I missing here?

I am using versions pandas 0.16.2 np19py26_0, iopro 1.7.1 np19py27_p0, and python 2.7.10 0 under Linux.

Comment: What is the dtype of your date column you created?  I suspect some of your values in INDATUMA are not properly being converted using `pd.to_datetime()`.

Comment: @khammel Possible if you say so, though I receive no warning or error about that. Why not? (Even more strange that my clunky version from before did run fine, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31684968/938408)

Comment: I see. I could use `pd.to_datetime(all_treatments['INDATUMA'],errors='raise')` or `pd.to_datetime(all_treatments['INDATUMA'],coerce=True)`

Comment: To_datetime() defaults to ignore errors.  Set `errors='raise'` to change.  Have you tried specifying the date format as in one of the answers to your previous question?

Comment: I think that coerce should solve your problem, assuming there is not way to correct the dates that won't convert.

Comment: Can you post the first few rows of `all_treatments['date']` and also `all_treatments['date'].dtype`?

Answer (score 0):

Once you check datatype of this column you will find out it wont be date time.
`all_treatments['date'].dtypes()` ---> object or other datatype

You need to convert to datetime first and then it will resolve.

```
all_treatments['date'] = pd.to_datetime(all_treatments['date'], errors='coerce')
```

In my case i am filtering out record and in result set all column values are none for date column, so column type got changed to object and getting this error.

if you think your result set can get empty records for date for any filter applied on df then df treat that column to other datatype. So for correction convert it to datetime obj and then use .dt. It will work fine.

[image: Solution]