# override pandas datetime conversion where coerce=True does not

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, coerce

I must have a mistaken date in my data, but I would rather just proceed setting this to missing. However, my attempt at coercing this failed, and I see no other option. What is there to do?

The relevant line is:

```
all_treatments['date'] = pd.to_datetime(all_treatments['INDATUMA'], format='%Y%m%d', coerce=True)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "treatments3_noiopro.py", line 76, in <module>
   all_treatments['date'] = pd.to_datetime(all_treatments['INDATUMA'], format='%Y%m%d', coerce=True)
 File "/home/seidav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 340, in to_datetime
   values = _convert_listlike(arg.values, False, format)
 File "/home/seidav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 333, in _convert_listlike
   raise e
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

I am using versions pandas 0.16.2 np19py26_0, iopro 1.7.1 np19py27_p0, and python 2.7.10 0 under Linux.

Comment: Try not provide `format`. It has been discussed here https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10154

Comment: When I don't give a format, then I get the entire column missing. At least in some testing scenarios.

Comment: As the link of @yangjie indicated, this was a bug in pandas 0.16.2, and will be fixed in 0.17.0. Normally, the format that you provide in this case ('%Y%m%d') should also be parsed without providing it. Can you show some example data where it gives a full missing column? Other option is maybe to try `infer_datetime_format=True`.

Comment: Well, I'm using a format and `coerce` because of answers I got here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31704221/938408

Comment: @joris Also, if I don't specify a format, all the years end up being 1970, while the first few lines on `INDATUMA` have values like `20010116`. The earliest date I have is from 1987. I wish I could use rawer number parsing, but of course, that also broke down: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31684968/938408

Comment: Is the columns of integer type? (normally has to be if it gives you dates in 1970, as it is then parsed as nanoseconds) Try to first do `astype(str)`, and then it should parse correctly.

Comment: Sure it is, .read_table stores it that way, which is way more memory efficient. So I need to convert it back on the fly? It works in testing, but might fail again once deployed:I am not sure why it would solve the problem why I was told to use a format and/or coerce in the first place. And why is it more robust than specifying a format myself?

Comment: No, normally specifying a format would be the correct solution. But you've hit a bug that I mentioned above that in some cases the `coerce=True` didn't work. So what I am proposing is a way to try to get around that bug, so without using `format`. What you can try is putting such a wrong date in the data that you are testing with, and see if it now coerces that correctly to NaN.